# Is the category of 2-categories, normal lax functors and lax natural transformations cartesian closed?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is the category of 2-categories, normal lax functors and lax natural transformations cartesian closed?

Given 2-categories C,D let $Fun(C,D)$ be the 2-category of normal (i.e. identity preserving) lax functors and lax natural transformations.
Does the canonical normal lax functor $Fun(C,D) \times C \to D$ induce for every 2-category B an equivalence
$$ Fun(B, Fun(C,D)) \simeq Fun(B \times C, D)?$$
Is this true for bicategories?

Comment: A closely related but different question: [MO 96611](https://mathoverflow.net/q/96611)

Comment: There are two questions here:

1. Is the category of 2-categories and normal lax functors cartesian closed?

2. If so, is the internal hom given by $[C,D] = $ the 2-category of normal lax functors $C \to D$, lax natural transformations, and modifications?

Comment: If you work out what a normal lax functor $\{0<1\} \times A \to B$ amounts to, you will see that the answer to all your questions is "no".

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Incidentally, do you know if the equivalence above still holds with $\times$ replaced with the lax Gray tensor product?

Comment: @Emily It doesn't hold in that case either.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Thanks! I was half-expecting the lax Gray tensor product to work; it would be nice if nevertheless there was still a different monoidal product making the equivalence above hold

Comment: For what its worth, there might be a skew monoidal closed structure on the category 2-Cat of 2-categories and 2-functors whose hom is Fun(C,D) as you define it above.  It is unlikely you would have the corresponding equivalence though, just the usual adjointness bijection.